# Which charset should I use to encode and decode 8 bit values?

Tags: java, windows, encoding, character-encoding

I have a problem with encoding and decoding specific byte values. I'm implementing an application, where I need to get String data, make some bit manipulation on it and return another String.

I'm currently getting `byte[]` values by `String.getbytes()`, doing proper manipulation and then returning String by constructor `String(byte[] data)`. The issue is, when some of bytes have specific values e.g. `-120`, `-127`, etc., the coding in the constructor returns `?` character, that is byte value `63`. As far as I know, these values are ones, that can't be printed on Windows, concerning the fact, that `-120` in Java is `10001000`, that is `\b` character according to [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Is there any charset, that I could use to properly code and decode every byte value (from -128 to 127)?

EDIT: I shall also say, that `ISO-8859-1` charset works pretty fine, but does not code language specific characters, such as ąęćśńźżół

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion regarding encodings, *not specific to Java*, so I'll try to help clear some of that up.

There do not exist any charsets nor encodings which use the code points from -128 to 0. If you treat the byte as an **unsigned** integer, then you get the range 0-255 which is valid for all the cp-* and isoo-8859-* charsets.

ASCII characters are in the range 0-127 and so appear valid whether you treat the int as signed or unsigned.

UTF-8 characters are **either** in the range 0-127 **or** double-byte characters with the first byte in the range 128-255.

You mention some Polish characters, so instead of ISO-8859-1 you should encode as **ISO-8859-2** or (preferably) **UTF-8**.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, ISO-8859-2 worked very well, but I ended up in using UTF-16 and coding characters in 2 bytes.